# How to get rid of Entity Framework attributes in auto-generated models?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, annotations

When generating a model from a table in Visual Studio, I get these attributes that I don't really feel that I have any use for. Is there a way to remove them?

```
public partial class TableModel
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]

    ...
```

Also another thing I wonder, if I've added a couple of custom properties to the model that do not exist as columns in the table, will they be removed next time I update the model? When I've added a column to the table, e.g.?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't modify these classes generated by Visual Studio. 
They are generated as partial classes, so you can create a new partial class and add your custom properties there like this:

```
public partial class TableModel 
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}
```

These should be in the same namespace as the generated classes.
This way you don't have to deal with the annotations you don't want to see, and if you regenerate your model your custom properties won't be deleted.

If you want to delete the annotations anyway, they can be easily deleted using Replace in files.. in VS (either by providing the exact text or a regular expression if there are many different annotations).